# I need to install pip on OSX. How can I do this?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I've downloaded virtualenv, distribute, get-pip.py, nose, and setuptools
I must install setuptools and pip. I have been spending hours and I cannnot figure it out. Can someone please tell me how I can install setuptools and pip?

Comment: "...spending hours and I cannnot figure it out" -- when it fails, does it indicate why?  Or you're asking where to start?

Comment: @BrianCain I'm asking where to start :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward. The same you do on other operating systems

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

`pip` also comes with Homebrew's default python

```
brew install python
```